# Como fazer uma previsão de um valor futuro?

Tags: c#

Estou fazendo uma calculadora para jogos de **FPS**, e nela, você informa o número de *Kills*, e o número de *Deaths*. Até ai tudo bem, consegui fazer a linha de comando para ela pegar os dois valores, e definir a porcentagem, mas na hora da previsão é que me perco. Estou começando agora com programação **C#** e não sei o que usar.

```
int kill, death;
double valor, KD_Porcentagem; 

valor = kill + death; //É SOMADO OS VALORES TOTAIS  
KD_Porcentagem = (kill * 100) / valor;//MULTIPLICADO O REQUERIDO POR 100, E DIVIDIDO PELA SOMA
```

Simples, simplesmente fiz regra de três, colocando que o valor é igual a 100% e que kill é igual a KD_Porcentagem. Tentei fazer o mesmo, mas não deu certo. Me baseio em um calculadora com o mesmo esquema, e mesma idéia, na qual acontece o seguinte:

Para kill = 90

e death = 30

KD_Porcentagem = 75%

Já na previsão, ocorre o seguinte :

Previsão:

Kill/Death 76%: Kill menos Death no periodo tem que ser: 3

Kill/Death 77%: Kill menos Death no periodo tem que ser: 8

Kill/Death 78%: Kill menos Death no periodo tem que ser: 14

Kill/Death 79%: Kill menos Death no periodo tem que ser: 20

Tentei de tudo já, mas não consigo bolar nada... Poderiam ajudar?

Comment: Que tipo de previsão você quer fazer? Previsão do Tempo (Hehe)? Tente explicar melhor o que pretende e qual problema está enfrentado em tentar resolve-lo, para que possamos lhe ajudar.

Comment: Quero prever o numero, que adicionado ao Kill aumente a porcentagem, lembrando que pode ser qualquer numero em um intervalo entre (int KD_Porcentagem) + 0.5 e (int KD_Porcentagem) + 1.0, no caso,  se a porcentagem inteira for 75, eu poderia pegar qualquer numero entre 75.5 e 76, pois o numero será arredondado sempre que chegar em um desses valores. Deu pra entender? xD

Comment: `"lembrando que pode ser qualquer número em um intervalo usando aquela fórmula que eu nunca mencionei antes..."` Não. Ninguém aqui conhece as variáveis do seu programa e nem as regras de negócio. Não há problema em editar a pergunta para conter mais informações e deixá-la mais clara, ok? Ajude-nos a entender o problema e nós o ajudaremos a resolvê-lo ;)

Comment: Por favor use a opção [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/39641/edit) de sua pergunta, e passe as informações necessárias para que uma pessoa/programador que NÃO esteja no seu lado olhando para seu código fonte e vendo seu dedo sendo apontado para o problema possa entender seu problema e talvez (dependendo da previsão do tempo) possa lhe ajudar.

Comment: Ainda não está claro...

Comment: Vc tá com uma lógica errada. Se o jogador tem 90 kills, e 30 deaths, o K/D dele é 3, não pode ser de 75% já que é Kill/Death... Tem que ver isso ai

Answer (score 1):

Nada que listas e regra de 3 nao resolva... Nossa amiga matemática ira nos ajudar nessa...

Voce pode fazer de varias formas... media ou soma dos kills/deaths diarios... e fazer uma projeção desses valores diante de uma base(jogos ganhos/horas jogadas/%melhora por jogo)... ai sim voce ter uma previsao sendo ela crescente ou decrescente.

Caso seja um jogo que ganhe XP/Level... seria mais interessante ainda... pois voce informaria o valor atual de ganho de xp... e ele ira fazer uma projecao de quando voce chegara em certo nivel.

Eu faria da seguinte maneira...

```
//criando nossa classe de dados
public class Dado
{
  Datetime datahora { get; set; }
  int kills { get; set; }
  int deaths { get; set; }
}

//criando uma lista desses dados...
//apos inserir varias essa lista contera varios dados... entao voce pode começar a brincar com eles... com alguns foreachs e if...

//instanciando a lista
List<Dado> ListaDados = new List<Dado>();

//instanciando um dado
Dado d = new Dado();
d.datahora = DateTime.Now();
d.kills = 120;
d.deaths = 60;

//adicionando o dado na lista...
ListaDados.Add(d);
```

Agora sua lista tem um dado... voce pode mostrar essa lista em um DataGridView(utilizando windows forms)...

```
DGV.DataSource = ListaDados.ToList();
```

E podemos andar nessa lista e fazer algumas contas matematicas... como uma media de kills por exemplo...

```
int totalelementoslista = ListaDados.Count;
int killstotais = 0;
int mortestotais = 0;
foreach (Dado d in ListaDados)//percorrendo a lista de dados
{
    killstotais += d.kills;
    mortestotais += d.deaths;
    int mediakillsdessejogo = d.kills / d.deaths; //ai voce guarda em algum outro lugar se quiser
}

    int mediakills = killstotais / mortestotais; // voce tem a media de kills de todos os jogos juntos.
```

**UPDATE:**
Voce explicou um pouco a sua necessidade... seria criar uma projeção futura de kills/deaths referente a uma porcentagem... e isso e bem facil de se fazer...
Cria uma lista dados nova... e gere ela utilizando um for... gerando valores nessa lista utilizando a matematica. ai voce tera os dados la dentro... tudo certinho ai voce pode colocar ate em um grafico de curva... e ficara bem show!

Answer (score 1):

A resposta do daniloloko esta correta, mas acho que poderia simplificar.

*A resposta abaixa vale para previsões nas 5 próximas porcentagens.*
**pela matemática**

```
PARA AUMENTAR EM UM A PORCENTAGEM É NECESSÁRIO
100(X+killinicial)/killinicial+deathinicial+X = porcentagem+1
100x+100killinicial/valorinicial+x=porcentagem+1
100x+100killinicial=(valorinicial+x)(porcentagem+1)
100x+100killinicial=valorinicial*(porcentagem+1)+x*(porcentagem+1)
100x-x*(porcentagem+1)=valorinicial*(porcentagem+1)-100killinicial
x=(valorinicial*(porcentagem+1)-100killinicial)/(100-porcentagem+1)
```

seu código

```
    int kill, death,x;
double valor, KD_Porcentagem; 

valor = kill + death; //É SOMADO OS VALORES TOTAIS  
KD_Porcentagem = (kill * 100) / valor;//MULTIPLICADO O REQUERIDO POR 100, E DIVIDIDO PELA SOMA
KD_porcentagem = KD_Porcentagem % 100// PEGA SÓ A PARTE INTEIRA. FACILITANDO NOSSA VIDA.
x=((valor*(KD_Porcentagem+1))-100*kill)/(100-KD_Porcentage+1)
```

no seu exemplo você tinha:

Para kill = 90

e death = 30

KD_Porcentagem = 75%

valor: 120

pela a minha formula

x = (120*76)-9000/24
x =  5

o que mostra que seu exemplo esta errado pois:
nesse novo exemplo temos 
k-95 D-30 valor 125
9500/125=76%

completando seu código vc faz um for para quantas vezes quiser e só reatribui os valores.
se não quiser perder os valores de kill e death utilize Backup das variáveis.

seu código com as 5 saidas:

```
        int kill, death,x;
double valor, KD_Porcentagem; 


valor = kill + death; //É SOMADO OS VALORES TOTAIS  
KD_Porcentagem = (kill * 100) / valor;//MULTIPLICADO O REQUERIDO POR 100, E DIVIDIDO PELA SOMA
//mostra a porcentagem atual com kill death.

//faz a previsão
for(int y=0;y<5;y++)
{
   valor = kill + death; //É SOMADO OS VALORES TOTAIS  
   KD_Porcentagem = (kill * 100) / valor;//MULTIPLICADO O REQUERIDO POR 100, E DIVIDIDO PELA SOMA
   KD_porcentagem = KD_Porcentagem % 100// PEGA SÓ A PARTE INTEIRA. FACILITANDO NOSSA VIDA.
   x=((valor*(KD_Porcentagem+1))-100*kill)/(100-KD_Porcentage+1);
   //mostra x
   kill=kill+x;
}
```

Comment: pode formatar melhor seu código e os textos para que seja mais fácil de entender?